# How to identify all existing strings within templates for translation purposes?

Tags: angularjs

I have quite a big angular project with lots of smaller html templates, directives etc.

As I am currently trying to move all existing "hard-coded" output strings into an angular translate translation provider I am wondering if there's a more efficient way to identify all existing strings instead of manually searching for it?

**Update**

Just as an example - I am developing with IntelliJ IDE (in my case PHPStorm). When checking the HTML files I usually see unformatted (means not syntax-highlighted) parts - these are usually strings which I have to identify - if there would be some regex/other search opportunity to highlight these non-highlighted parts these would extremely help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of an automated way of doing this - and i doubt there is one -, but you could just switch to another language (if you have translations for more than 1) and then go through your app.

It's easier to see it :-)

Comment: Thanks @Johannes Ferner. Please see my update as well. Following you're approach is a smart way to do it manually.